# Are the publicity badges awarded multiple times?

Tags: support, publicity-badges

Just curious. Are the new *Announcer*, *Booster* and *Publicist* badges awarded multiple times like the *Nice Answer* and similar badges?

---

**UPDATE:** It [was announced today](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/) on the blog that these badges are awarded once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the description on the badge page says they can be awarded multiple times, they can be. If it does not, they cannot.

Comment: It doesn't say it, so they can't be :) ... Most badge descriptions that are awarded only once include the word "First...". Such as "First bounty...", "First upvote...", "Hit the rep cap for the first time", etc... Do you think these new badges should explicitly state that they are awarded for the "First link shared link to a question that was visited by x visitors"?

Comment: I don't think the badge page mentions which badges can and cannot be awarded multiple times. (http://stackoverflow.com/badges)